# PHP MongoDB Query into an array with an unknown key

Tags: php, mongodb, key

I have a mongoDB set up like so:

```
fieldName: {
  "1": {
      client: "name-here",
      subfield: "more-junk-here"
   },
   "2": {
      client: "another-client-name-here",
      subfield: "more-data"
   },
   "3": {
      client: "client-num-3",
      subfield: "i-like-turkey-sandwiches"
   }
}
```

How do I query for "i-like-turkey-sandwiches", without knowing it's in position 3, and without doing a search of the whole document? I started writing this, but am completely stumped how to do the search...

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array('fieldName' => 'i-like-turkey-sandwiches));
```

Answer (score 1):

(edit: My answer is valid only if fieldName content is an array of subdocument and not a document with "1"/2/3 as key and subdocument as value)

If you query with

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(
              array('fieldName.subfield' => 'i-like-turkey-sandwiches'));
```

It will return you all documents where you have a subfield inside a fieldName field with this value.